# Python is writing data in csv file in list fomat

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

I have two lists and want to write them to a csv file. I wrote the code to write the csv file. After running the program, data is get written to the csv file. But when I open the csv file, the data is stored in list format like:

```
[u'abc coffee'],[u'abc address']
```

But I want to write the csv file in the normal form like:

```
"abc coffee, abc address"
```

How can I do this?

```
import csv

ifile = open("ouput.csv","w")
writer = csv.writer(ifile)
company_name =["abc coffee"]        
rating_count = ["abc address"]

writer.writerow([company_name,rating_count])
ifile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`company_name` and `rating_count` are lists already and you're packing them into another list on writing. Do

```
writer.writerow(company_name + rating_count)
```

instead.

Comment: After doing this it gave me the following error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0'"

Comment: Try replacing the spaces in `"abc coffee"` and `"abc address"` with actual spaces. Did you copy and paste those strings from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

ifile = open("ouput.csv","w")
writer = csv.writer(ifile)

company_name =["abc coffee"]
rating_count = ["abc address"]

company_name.extend(rating_count) *add another item into the same list*

writer.writerow(company_name) *send the list to writer object which writes it to file*

ifile.close()
```

Comment: what if i am having more than three list of above type?

Comment: Depends on the input. I'd rather store data as strings and then create a list out of it.

`company_name = 'abc coffee'`
`address = 'blah blah blah'`
`rating = 3.5`

`data = [company_name, address, rating]`

`writer.writerow(data)`

What is your input type?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly write the list as a concatenated string using:

```
writer.writerow([' '.join(company_name), ' '.join(rating_count)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include csv library and there is no need to use lists to achieve that kind of an output.

```
ifile = open("ouput.txt","w")
company_name ="abc coffee"        
rating_count = "abc address"

ifile.write(company_name + ", " +rating_count + "\n")
ifile.close()
```

will be enough.

Comment: If you have strings that contain the field delimiter (eg: `,`) this will produce incorrect non-quoted output (it'll also help to add a `+ '\n'` as well)

Comment: After doing this it gives me the error "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Comment: @NeerajSharma this code has the potential to create incorrect output - but it won't raise that error as it's written :p

Comment: @JonClements I've added "\n" to the end.

Comment: @wizofwor and by the time you've done that - you've written a  non-standard and less efficient version of the csv module :)

Answer (score 0):

after spending time finally I came with the solution. I simply convert the above two list in string and then while writing them in csv i convert them in list and concatenate them. So the final code is :

```
 import csv

 ifile = open("ouput.csv","w")
 writer = csv.writer(ifile)

 company_name ="abc coffee"
 rating_count = "abc address"

 writer.writerow([company_name]+[rating_count])

 ifile.close()
```

thank so much everyone for your help.